# How do I print at the bottom of the shell without reordering code? (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x

Example of My Question:

```
food_choice=input("Would you like to eat a burrito or a pizza? ")

if food_choice=='burrito':

    print('You should go to a Mexican restaurant!')

if food_choice=='pizza':

    print('You should go to an Italian restaurant!')

    print('Don't forget to save me a slice of pizza!') #<----- How do I print this at the bottom?


print('Everyone loves to eat!')

print('Have a good time at your restaurant!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to solve this.

```
after = ""
food_choice=input("Would you like to eat a burrito or a pizza? ")
if food_choice=='burrito':
    print('You should go to a Mexican restaurant!')
if food_choice=='pizza':
    print('You should go to an Italian restaurant!')
    after = 'Don't forget to save me a slice of pizza!'

print('Everyone loves to eat!')

print('Have a good time at your restaurant!')
if after:
    print(after)
```